# Customizing menu link output (add badge)

Tags: theming, routes

I am new to drupal. I want to customize menu link

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs sub-menu"><li class="menu-1308 first active"><a href="/" class="active">Top</a></li>
<li class="menu-1309"><a href="/all">All Posts</a></li>
<li class="menu-1310 last"><a href="/discussed">Discussed</a></li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs sub-menu"><li class="menu-1308 first active"><a href="/" class="active">Top</a></li>
<li class="menu-1309"><a href="/all">All Posts<span class="badge">42</span> </a></li>
<li class="menu-1310 last"><a href="/discussed">Discussed</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just add `<span class="badge">42</span>` next to "All Post" menu link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function you'll need:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

That allows you to overwrite the standard theme function. You could do an if statement to check for that specific menu link ID and do a custom output.

You'll need to put that in template.php within your custom theme and replace "theme_" in the function name with the name of your theme